# Solve the IVP $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the Initial Value Problem $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2=0$$for$$y(0)=2, y'(0)=1$$

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

$$y''=-y'^2$$

So $y''/y' =-y'$

$$\ln|y'|=-y+C$$

$$y'=e^{-y+C}$$

$\frac 1{y'} = Ae^y$, where $A=e^{-C}$

Integrate w.r.t. $y$:

$$x(y)=Ae^y+k$$

$$y(x)=\ln (\frac{x-k}A)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

In case of $\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$ , solve it for $y$.

In case of $\frac{dy}{dx}\neq 0$ , integrate :
$\qquad \frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$